# How to redirect inside a class-based component with Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I need to make a redirect from inside an `onSubmit` call. Currently, the full code is as below, and I need to keep `CampaignNew` as a class-based component. How can I do it?

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Layout from "../../components/layoyt";
import { Form, Button, Input, Message } from "semantic-ui-react";
import factory from "../../components/factory";
import web3 from "../../components/web3";

class CampaignNew extends Component {
  state = {
    minimumContribution: "0",
    errorMessage: "",
    loading: false,
  };

  onSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // Prevent the browser to attemp submission at initialization

    this.setState({ loading: true, errorMessage: "" });

    try {
      await window.ethereum.enable();
      const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
      console.log("Account :" + accounts[0]);

      await factory.methods.createCampaign(this.state.minimumContribution).send({
        from: accounts[0],
      });

      //// !!PUSH_TO_('/')

      this.setState({ loading: false });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ errorMessage: err.message });
      this.setState({ loading: false });
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <h3>Create a Campaign</h3>
        <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} error={!!this.state.errorMessage}>
          <Form.Field>
            <label>Minimum Contribution</label>
            <Input
              label="wei"
              labelPosition="right"
              value={this.state.minimumContribution}
              onChange={(event) => this.setState({ minimumContribution: event.target.value })}
            />
          </Form.Field>

          <Message
            error
            header="There was some errors with your submission"
            content={this.state.errorMessage}
          />
          <Button loading={this.state.loading} primary>
            Create
          </Button>
        </Form>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}

export default CampaignNew;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`withRouter`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#withrouter) to pass the [`router`](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#router-object) object as a prop to `CampaignNew`. To do so, first import `withRouter` from Next.js:

```js
import { withRouter } from "next/router";
```

Then change how you are exporting `CampaignNew` to:

```js
export default withRouter(CampaignNew);
```

Now you have access to the `router` in `props`, :

```js
onSubmit = async (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  this.props.router.push("/about");
};
```

Comment: its best to use `replace` instead of `push`

Comment: Depending on how you wanna alter the browser navigation history, yeah, `replace` may make sense. But the main point here is to show how to can redirect.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! What the difference between `replace` and `push`? @YoussoufOumar @Dean Van Greunen?

Comment: Glad I could help @Rego! About your last question, this might help: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/router#routerreplace.

Comment: Got it, nice. So `replace` seems more reasonable. Thanks again!